# IIS express dont respect serviceCredentials

Tags: wcf, iis-express

I have testing WCF service and i want to deploy it for development purposes to IIS Express (not classical IIS)

part of my Web.config

```
</serviceHostingEnvironment>

<services>

  <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="test">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

</services>


<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>


    <behavior name="test">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="My"
                            x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```

When i deploy it on IIS express everything works fine... Except it is on port 44300 (that is ok) but it use IIS Express own certificate generated on iis express installation.

I clearly specify so he should use my certificate located by thumbprint and by value "XXXXXXX...."

How to force IIS express to respect that service behavior part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i have a solution.
What i wrote is different kind of certificate - its for service authentication on client.

Certificate used for SSL connection establish is really set with this command:

`netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 appid={214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74a} certhash=YOURCERTHASHHERE`

Azure projects - web roles do this on project startup automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice blog post by #SCOTT HANSELMAN on this:

```
 http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx
```

Comment: jep i read that but is this command: "netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 appid={214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74a} certhash=YOURCERTHASHHERE " what i want ? Because i have my configuration in web.config not in some commands elsewhere

Comment: it's basically telling iis express what certificate to use on what port, please follow this properly i have tried it already and works :)

Comment: thanks for help. I was mistaken because Azure web roles do this command automaticaly and that was really confusing for me

Comment: glad you got what you needed :)